# Setting the panel size according to the size of the inner elements?

Tags: java, swing, resize, jscrollpane

I have a *JScrollPane* that contains another panel with *GridBagLayout* (which is withing a *JTabbedPane* withing a *JSplitPane*, but I don't think that makes a difference).

What I want is simple: if the size of the *ScrollPane* is too small, display the vertical scrollbar so that all elements are visible. To achieve that, I wrote a simple function for the *ComponentListener.componentResized* which takes position of the last element, add the height and substracts the *offset* of the panel itself:

```
int prefSize = lastButton.getLocationOnScreen().y + lastButton.getSize().height - myGridPanel.getLocationOnScreen().y;
myGridPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, prefSize));
```

Sadly, this only works *after* I manually resize the window. Before that, the scrollbar doesn't reach until the end so that a few rows are unreachable and the topmost JTextPane element is partly hidden. As I said, as soon as I resize the window (increase or decrease the size, vertically or horizontally), every element is correct and the scrollbar is perfect as well, scrolling exactly until after the last element.

I was able to improve the situation by adding the following when creating the frame or switching to the tab (*stateChanged()*):

```
mainFrame.pack();
setPreferredSize();
mainFrame.setSize(dim);
mainFrame.revalidate();
mainFrame.repaint();
```

Now, all rows except the last one are scrollable, while the last row is only visible ~30%. Again...as soon as I manually resize the frame, everything looks as intended.

It feels like I'm missing something simple, but I have no idea what it could be. Searching around I saw the suggestion of adding *setPreferredSize(panel.getPreferredSize());* , but that also didn't help.

I would appreciate any help on this!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> Searching around I saw the suggestion of adding setPreferredSize(panel.getPreferredSize()); ,

Wrong. You should never try to manage the size of the panel. That is the job of the layout manager. Don't use setPreferredSize()!

If you let the layout manager do its job, then layout manager will dynamically calculate its own preferred size and the scrollbars will appear automatically as required.

> I wrote a simple function for the ComponentListener.componentResized

There is no need to use a component listener.

The general usage of a scrollpane is to add it to the CENTER of the BorderLayout of the frame. Then as the frame is resized the size of the scrollpane changes. The scrollbars will then appear/disappear as required.

Comment: Hmm, that sounds great and all, but that doesn't help me *at all*. I've tried `BorderLayout`, `BoxLayout`, etc, but I don't know how to get my layout to work without `GridBagLayout`. And this certainly doesn't work when I leave out anything `setPreferredSize()`-related.

Comment: @Markstar, well, whenever you ask a question you should include a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. If you follow my advice it will work. We can't guess what you are doing to cause it not to work.

Comment: Yes, I know. I just assumed/hoped that there was something simple that I overlooked. As i said, I can't use `BorderLayout`, because then the text elements won't resize correctly (with linebreaks, etc.) and nesting also doesn't work. I'll see if I can work out a minimal example.